# Init basic_string c++

Tags: c++, string, tchar, stdstring

I have this method which is not from me. Someone here gave me that.

```
void captureNewPictures(std::vector<Picture> &vecPicsOld, const tstring &dir)
```

And I've tried to init this "dir" variable without success. I'm beginner in C++ and watched out all the possible doc (or almost :p ) all day long. Could someone explain me how to pass a string value to "dir" please, regarding tstring is defined by

```
typedef std::basic_string <TCHAR> tstring ;
```

PS : I saw I could remove the reference value to "dir&", is this a problem for after ?
PS2 : If you have a nice doc explaining string values and their corresponding fields this zould be very very great ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tstring` has been types this way so that you'll get either ascii or Unicode strings depending on your compilation flags.

To initialize the string do something like this:

```
tstring greeting = _T("hello, world");
```

The `_T` macro will convert your string to a wide string by prefixing it with `L` in a Unicode build, otherwise it will leave it as a regular ascii string.

Comment: `TEXT` is certainly defines in Microsoft compilers, I'm not sure about others, though. You pretty much always see the `_T` macro used.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
tstring yourString = _T("<your string here>");
captureNewPictures(yourVecPicsOld, yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows box to test this on, but

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef char TCHAR;

typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

void somefunc(const tstring &dir)
{
    std::cout << dir << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    tstring foo = "hello world";
    somefunc(foo);

    somefunc("goodbye world");
}
```

works with GCC on my Mac OS X box. Does the above work for you? What is the exact error you get?

Comment: thanks but _T seems to be ok. I cannot try now, I have other errors in my code :)\